# Line integral of $\vec G=3y\vec i-3x\vec j$ along the path $r(t)=\cos t\vec i + \sin t\vec j$ isn't zero?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, parametric

Here is a diagram depicting the question:

[image]

$C_2$ is I think parameterized by  $r(t)=\cos t\vec i + \sin t\vec j$, where $3\pi /4 \leq t \leq 7\pi /4 $

The vector field in question is $\vec G=3y\vec i-3x\vec j$, and I want to find $\int_{C_2} \vec G \cdot d\vec r $.

$\vec G \cdot r(t) = 3\cos t\sin t - 3\cos t\sin t =0$, so we have:

$$\int_{C_2} \vec G \cdot d\vec r = \int_{C_2} 0 = 0 $$

But apparently the line integral evaluates to $-6\pi$. Where did I go wrong? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm learning this for the first time and without supervision

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate $\vec G \cdot d\vec r(t)$, not $\vec G \cdot \vec r(t)$.

$$\vec G \cdot d\vec r(t) 
=3(\sin t i - \cos t j)\cdot(-\sin t i + \cos t  j) d\theta$$

$$=-3(\sin^2t+\cos^2 t)d\theta
= -3d\theta \ne0$$

Comment: Ah okay, thank you! This is a bit strange though: $\int_{3\pi /4}^{7\pi /4} -3 dt = -3\pi $, but the answer was $-6\pi$. Would you know anything about this?

Comment: @JamesRonald - Appears puzzling to me too. Did you verify the radius of circular path?